# Could not determine JSON object type for anonymous type

Tags: c#, json, .net

I am trying to create a JSON object which should look like this when converted into a string:

```
{
    "ts":1634712287000,
    "values":{
        "temperature":26,
        "humidity":87
    }
}
```

This is how I tried to do it by creating a `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject`:

```
new JObject(new
{
    Ts = 1634712287000,
    Values = new JObject(new
    {
        Temperature = 26,
        Humidity = 87
    }),
});
```

With this code I get the following error:

```
Could not determine JSON object type for type <>f__AnonymousType2`2[System.Int32,System.Int32]."}   System.ArgumentException
```

I am obviously doing something wrong but I cannot figure out how to do this correctly.
What am I doing wrong and how can I create a `JObject` like in my example above via code?

Comment: It's way easier to create a model and serialize. https://dotnetfiddle.net/RaaF2S

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create the whole anonymous object first, and then you can convert it, so:

```cs
var obj = new {
    ts = 1634712287000,
    values = new {
        temperature = 26,
        humidity = 87
    },
};

var json = JObject.FromObject(obj).ToString(Formatting.Indented);
```

Output:

```json
{
  "ts": 1634712287000,
  "values": {
    "temperature": 26,
    "humidity": 87
  }
}
```

Comment: Should be the accepted answer. I did the same mistake today, I used the constructor with an object instance instead of JObject.FromObject(obj).

Answer (score 2):

We can try to use [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) with an anonymous object if you don't want to create a class.

```
var jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new {
    ts = 1634712287000,
    Values = new {
        Temperature = 26,
        Humidity = 87
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

To add the System.Text.Json Version:

```
using System;
using System.Text.Json;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var myAnonymousModel = new
        {
            Ts = 1634712287000,
            Values = new
            {
                Temperature = 26,
                Humidity = 87
            }
        };
        var camelCasePolicyOptions = 
             new JsonSerializerOptions(){ PropertyNamingPolicy = 
                                            JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase,
                                           WriteIndented = true };
        Console.WriteLine(
              JsonSerializer.Serialize(myAnonymousModel, 
                                       camelCasePolicyOptions ));   
    }
}
```

Output:

```json
{
  "ts": 1634712287000,
  "values": {
    "temperature": 26,
    "humidity": 87
  }
}
```

See https://dotnetfiddle.net/JPUJRv